# Using Authentication.asmx Login gives HTTP 500 error

Tags: 2010, authentication, soap

I try to login to SharePoint 2010 via `Authentication.asmx` service from native C++ application and get `HTTP 500` response.
I saw `HTTP 500` before in case of malformed SOAP request but what's wrong with it now?
Username and password are the same as used to response `HTTP 401`. Should I use "LoginName" `i:0#.w|myserver\myname` instead (`HTTP 400` in that case)?

```
POST 
https://myserver.com/_vti_bin/Authentication.asmx

Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: soap_body_length

Body
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Login xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <username>myname@myserver.com</username>
      <password>mypassword</password>
    </Login>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```